# Fastest way to calculate cell-wise percentiles for raster brick [R]

Tags: r, loops, statistics, raster

I'd like to calculate several statistics for each cell of a raster brick (+50 layers, 70,000,000 cells) such as the median. This little piece of code is working but incredibly slow... :

```
    r <- raster(ncol=3000, nrow=2000)
    r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
    s <- stack(x=c(r, r*2, r))
    file <- brick(x=c(r, r*2, r))
    q25 <- file[[1]]
    i=0
    for(i in 1:ncell(file)){
      progress(i, max.value = ncell(file))
      q25[i] <- unname(quantile(file[i],.5,na.rm=TRUE))
    }
```

q25 is a raster layer (exact same to 'file') but only a single layer (not a brick).

I'd be happy for any suggestions how to speed things up.

Thanks!

Comment: Can u show a small reproducible example for others to test

Comment: Thanks, I just added a reproducable raster brick. Please note that my brick has much more cells.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid looping over cells, that it is too slow.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=300, nrow=200)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
s <- stack(r, r*2, r)
```

Your approach

```
q25 <- raster(s)
for(i in 1:ncell(q25)){
   q25[i] <- quantile(s[i], .5, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

A better approach (~10x faster, see below)

```
q1 <- calc(s, fun=function(x) quantile(x, .5, na.rm=TRUE))
```

But for the median, it is faster (~37x) to use

```
q2 <- calc(s, fun=function(x)median(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Speed comparison:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:ncell(q25)){ q25[i] <- quantile(s[i], .5, na.rm=TRUE)  })
#user  system elapsed 
#69.24   13.90   83.71 
system.time( q1 <- calc(s, fun=function(x)quantile(x, .5, na.rm=TRUE)))
#user  system elapsed 
#7.81    0.00    7.81 
system.time(q2 <- calc(s, fun=function(x)median(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
#user  system elapsed 
#2.23    0.00    2.23
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The process still takes more than 6 hours and I would like to further speed things up, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up more by running the calc functions above in parallel. This link has some info on how. Good luck...
https://www.gis-blog.com/increasing-the-speed-of-raster-processing-with-r-part-33-cluster/